# Access Session attributes in aspect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to access session attributes in an aspectj @Aspect. 
When I do so I have the exception bellow.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class GlobalFilter {

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

private static HttpSession httpSession() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    return attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
}

@Before("execution(public !void org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.find*(..))")
public void beforeFind() {
    HttpSession httpSession = httpSession();

    Long idClient = (Long) httpSession.getAttribute(SessionKeys.ID_CLIENT);
    Long idUser = (Long) httpSession.getAttribute(SessionKeys.ID_USER);

    if (idClient != null) {

        enableFilter(DatabaseFilter.ID_USER, DatabaseFilter.ID_USER_PARAM_NAME, idUser);
        enableFilter(DatabaseFilter.ID_CLIENT, DatabaseFilter.ID_CLIENT_PARAM_NAME, idClient);
        enableFilter(DatabaseFilter.ID_CLIENT_BY_USER, DatabaseFilter.ID_CLIENT_PARAM_NAME, idClient);
    }
}

private void enableFilter(String filterName, String filterParamName, Long filterValue) {
    Filter filterUser = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter(filterName);
    filterUser.setParameter(filterParamName, filterValue);
}
}
```

I also tried to inject the session like this :

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

It seems like the HttpSession and my aspect are not executed in the same thread which is causing the problem.

So I have two questions :
- Is there a way to get session information in the aspect ? how ?

- if i just ignore the exception, will this be a problem if two users use the application at the same time ? Is my aspect thread safe or will the two sessions get mixed up in the aspect ?

I am using spring boot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `RequestContextHolder` retrieves the current request context from a ThreadLocal variable, that is set and cleared by `DispatcherServlet`, `DispatcherPortlet`, `RequestContextListener` or `RequestContextFilter`. Do you have any of those set up in your spring context?

Comment: yes i tried to create a configuration "@Configuration @WebListener public class MyRequestContextListener extends RequestContextListener {}"

and i also tried  "@Bean public RequestContextListener 
requestContextListener(){ return new RequestContextListener(); }"

but i still have the same exception. Can this exception cause the aspect to mixup the session attributes between two sessions in runtime ?

Comment: If you are confident that the request attributes are indeed stored in the threadlocal variable managed by `RequestContextHolder` (check with breakpoints on this class), then you probably face this problem because the data access happens on a different thread than the web request, so the attributes stored in the threadlocal are not available.